# How does DataAnnotationsModelBinder work with custom ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, viewmodel

I'm trying to use the [DataAnnotationsModelBinder](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) in order to use data annotations for server-side validation in ASP.NET MVC.

Everything works fine as long as my ViewModel is just a simple class with immediate properties such as

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar {get;set;}
}
```

However, the `DataAnnotationsModelBinder` causes a `NullReferenceException` when trying to use a complex `ViewModel`, such as

```
public class Foo
{
    public class Baz
    {
        public int Bar {get;set;}
    }

    public Baz MyBazProperty {get;set;}
}
```

This is a big problem for views that render more than one LINQ entity because I really prefer using custom `ViewModel`s that include several LINQ entities instead of untyped ViewData arrays.

The `DefaultModelBinder` does not have this problem, so it seems like a bug in `DataAnnotationsModelBinder`. Is there any workaround to this?

**Edit:** A possible workaround is of course to expose the child object's properties in the ViewModel class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Baz myBazInstance;

    [Required]
    public string ExposedBar
    {
        get { return MyBaz.Bar; }
        set { MyBaz.Bar = value; }
    }

    public Baz MyBaz
    {
        get { return myBazInstance ?? (myBazInstance = new Baz()); }
        set { myBazInstance = value; }
    }

    #region Nested type: Baz

    public class Baz
    {
        [Required]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
}

#endregion
```

But I'd prefer not to have to write all this extra code. The `DefaultModelBinder` works fine with such hiearchies, so I suppose the `DataAnnotationsModelBinder` should as well.

**Second Edit:** It looks like this is indeed a bug in `DataAnnotationsModelBinder`. However, there is hope this might be fixed before the next ASP.NET MVC framework version ships. See [this forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1418796/3139121.aspx#3139121) for more details.

Comment: i have a similar model but generally edit individual objects at a time. for example: i have an Announcement object that may or may not have a series of attachments (images, PDFs), but i edit the Announcement by itself and so dont force the validator to descend into the child objects of Announcement. I'll then edit the child objects separately - same view, but different POST action. i'm interested now - how do your actions work that ur validating huge object trees? and how does the UI work for that?

Comment: Regarding Views: I have described how to do this at http://devermind.com/linq/aspnet-mvc-using-custom-viewmodels-with-post-action-methods

Regarding Validation: Until now I've been using Server-side validation in the same manner as described in Scott Gu's tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx. My controller then collects the validation errors from different entities like this: 
 ModelState.AddRuleViolations(model.User.GetRuleViolations(),"User");
ModelState.AddRuleViolations(model.Company.GetRuleViolations(),"Company");

Comment: I'm sure it's a bug somewhere in my model binder code, but I haven't had the time to track it down. More pressing deliverables have been in the way. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue today. Like yourself I don't tie my View directly to my Model but use an intermediate ViewDataModel class that holds an instance of the Model and any parameters / configurations I'd like to sent of to the view.

I ended up modifying `BindProperty` on the DataAnnotationsModelBinder to circumvent the `NullReferenceException`, and I personally didn't like properties only being bound if they were valid (see reasons below).

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                         ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
                                         PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) {
    string fullPropertyKey = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);

    // Only bind properties that are part of the request
    if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.DoesAnyKeyHavePrefix(fullPropertyKey)) {
        var innerContext = new ModelBindingContext() {
            Model = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(bindingContext.Model),
            ModelName = fullPropertyKey,
            ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
            ModelType = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType,
            ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
        };

        IModelBinder binder = Binders.GetBinder(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
        object newPropertyValue = ConvertValue(propertyDescriptor, binder.BindModel(controllerContext, innerContext));
        ModelState modelState = bindingContext.ModelState[fullPropertyKey];
        if (modelState == null)
        {
            var keys = bindingContext.ValueProvider.FindKeysWithPrefix(fullPropertyKey);
            if (keys != null && keys.Count() > 0)
                modelState = bindingContext.ModelState[keys.First().Key];
        }
        // Only validate and bind if the property itself has no errors
        //if (modelState.Errors.Count == 0) {
            SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, newPropertyValue);
            if (OnPropertyValidating(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, newPropertyValue)) {

                OnPropertyValidated(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, newPropertyValue);
            }
        //}

        // There was an error getting the value from the binder, which was probably a format
        // exception (meaning, the data wasn't appropriate for the field)
        if (modelState.Errors.Count != 0) {
            foreach (var error in modelState.Errors.Where(err => err.ErrorMessage == "" && err.Exception != null).ToList()) {
                for (var exception = error.Exception; exception != null; exception = exception.InnerException) {
                    if (exception is FormatException) {
                        string displayName = GetDisplayName(propertyDescriptor);
                        string errorMessage = InvalidValueFormatter(propertyDescriptor, modelState.Value.AttemptedValue, displayName);
                        modelState.Errors.Remove(error);
                        modelState.Errors.Add(errorMessage);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also modified it so that it **always** binds the data on the property no matter if it's valid or not. This way I can just pass the model back to the view withouth invalid properties being reset to null.

**Controller Excerpt**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(ProfileViewDataModel model)
{
    FormCollection form = new FormCollection(this.Request.Form);
    wsPerson service = new wsPerson();
    Person newPerson = service.Select(1, -1);
    if (ModelState.IsValid && TryUpdateModel<IPersonBindable>(newPerson, "Person", form.ToValueProvider()))
    {
        //call wsPerson.save(newPerson);
    }
    return View(model); //model.Person is always bound no null properties (unless they were null to begin with)
}
```

My Model class (Person) comes from a webservice so I can't put attributes on them directly, the way I solved this is as follows:

**Example with nested DataAnnotations**

```
[Validation.MetadataType(typeof(PersonValidation))]
public partial class Person : IPersonBindable { } //force partial.

public class PersonValidation
{
    [Validation.Immutable]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Validation.Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Validation.StringLength(35)]
    [Validation.Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    CategoryItemNullable NearestGeographicRegion { get; set; }
}

[Validation.MetadataType(typeof(CategoryItemNullableValidation))]
public partial class CategoryItemNullable { }

public class CategoryItemNullableValidation
{
    [Validation.Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Validation.Range(1,10)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I bind a form field to `[ViewDataModel.]Person.NearestGeographicRegion.Text` & `[ViewDataModel.]Person.NearestGeographicRegion.Value` the ModelState starts validating them correctly and DataAnnotationsModelBinder binds them correctly as well.

This answer is not definitive, it's the product of scratching my head this afternoon.
It's not been properly tested, eventhough it passed the unit tests in [the project](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html) Brian Wilson started and most of my own limited testing. For true closure on this matter I would love to hear [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html) thoughts on this solution.

Comment: Seems to work great for me as well, at least judging by my first quick test. Thanks a lot! I'll let Brad know of your bugfix, perhaps he'll have some time to have a look.

Comment: Cool nice to know its working for you as well. One last hint if you bind to custom object arrays (see: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) Unlike that article mentions with this modelbinder you don't need the index field in fact it will error with but works fine without.

Answer (score 3):

The fix for this issue is simple, as Martijn has noted.

In the BindProperty method, you will find this line of code:

```
if (modelState.Errors.Count == 0) {
```

It should be changed to:

```
if (modelState == null || modelState.Errors.Count == 0) {
```

We are intending to include DataAnnotations support in MVC 2, which will include the DataAnnotationsModelBinder. This feature will be part of the first CTP.